# How to get Scaffold to Appear Over Top Notification Bar in Jetpack Compose?

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack

I want my scaffold to appear over the top of the notification bar, is this possible?

This is what I have (can't show much due to company policy):

[image]

I want the scaffold to go over the time and battery symbol.

This is what I want:

[image]

The above image is from Google Developers documentation site: https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/layouts/material#modal-drawers

My code:

```
Scaffold(
 scaffoldState = scaffoldState,
 topBar = {
  TopBarComposable() // Where you see the Edit button is bottom right
 },
 drawerContent = {
  DrawerContentComposable()
 },
 content = {
  ContentComposable() // The main screen thats under the Top Bar Composable
 },
 bottomBar = { BottomBarComposable() },
 drawerShape = RectangleShape
)
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: I would require the screenshot of the entire screen to diagnose the issue. Company doesn't want you to get a problem solved? Share the code

Answer (score 2):

Use `WindowCompat.setDecorFitsSystemWindows`

```
// Turn off the decor fitting system windows, which allows us to handle insets, including IME animations
WindowCompat.setDecorFitsSystemWindows(window, false)
```

Source: [Now In Android](https://github.com/android/nowinandroid)

Refer [here](https://github.com/android/nowinandroid/blob/main/app/src/main/java/com/google/samples/apps/nowinandroid/MainActivity.kt) for more details.

Note, you also have to handle padding manually.